# Storing API_KEY in Heroku

Tags: python, api, heroku

I have a Python code that I want to run 24/7. After doing a bit research, I decided to deploy my code on Heroku. In order for my code to run, it needs to get an API key; however, I want to store the API key in a secure place.

So I stored the key in Heroku's **config vars** using the CLI's command config:set. **However, I am not sure how to pull the key from config vars in order to store it in a variable in my code.**

I am very new to all of this so I would really appreciate your help. I am open to storing my API key as well using different methods, whatever gets the job done in a beginner-friendly manner (git-crypt? etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add what config vars you want to store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configvar is an environment variable available to the application at runtime:

```
api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", "default_val")
```

You could have a default value on local dev (if needed)